# get unique ahref from 2 string?

Tags: php, string

In my page i have 2 string like this:

```
$post_des = 'this is an <a href = "http://example.com/test"> example </a> string '; 

$post_detail = 'this is a new <a href = "http://example.com/test"> example </a> string ' ;
```

i want remove all the duplicate ahref in my page . Anyone can give me a solution?
I want to this :

```
$post_des = 'this is an <a href = "http://example.com/test"> example </a> string '; 

$post_detail = "this is a new example string " ;
```

Comment: You can remove the `href` tag by  `$post_detail = preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $post_detail);` But don't know how you find and iterate all the `href` tags in your page !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) Class for this eg:

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Google</a>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($anchors as $anchor){
    //Check each anchor href attribute
    if($anchor->getAttribute('href') == 'http://www.google.com'){
        $anchor->setAttribute('href','http://example.com');
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: but my ahref is a dynamic link,every page have different link , so i think i can't use comparison in this situation

Comment: then in the if that use if(in_array($anchor->getAttribute('href'),array('http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com'))){ add as many link as you want.

Comment: Is it ok ? I have about 2 milion links ( it's link of tags) and it increase everyday . i fear it would crash ? :(